# Possible DNS Issue Causing Timeout on Some Sites

Tags: wireless-networking, dns, internet, windows-10, internet-connection

I'm using Windows 10, and having a bit of a problem.

Whenever I'm on my home network, with my laptop - some sites will just timeout for me. One example is uakron.edu, whenever I connect using my laptop from my home wifi it times out. If I use the same laptop on my neighbors wifi, it works fine. If I use another laptop on my wifi, it works fine. I got a new router/modem, and that didn't fix anything. I then called my ISP (TWC) and they said everything was fine and they think it's just a DNS issue on my end which they won't fix. I tried fixing the DNS, and nothing worked. I then completely reset my laptop and it still didn't fix it. I've tried every browser, and nothing's working. Any ideas?

Comment: You can clarify if it actually DNS or some other issue by using a 'bad' site in an experiment. Find out the IP of the web site and try entering the IP address in your browser. If the web site appears then it is indeed a DNS issue. If it doesn't then you might have another issue like routing.

Comment: Okay, I did that by trying to connect to uakron.edu with just the IP. It times out as well. I did this when I was on the phone with TWC, and they said since it didn't appear that meant it was DNS. I don't believe they know what they're talking about.

Comment: It sounds like routing or firewalling. DNS can be checked with NSLOOKUP.

Comment: How would I find out if it's routing or firewall?

Answer (score 0):

When I ping uakron.edu it gets resolved to 130.101.217.74.
ping -a 130.101.217.74 resloves to wwwtest.uakron.edu
---All ping requests time out but if you get the same results above, DNS is working fine.

Tracert to the same IP results in time out.

I use chrome to go to "uakron.edu" and I was able to see the website.
I am also able to get to the website entering "130.101.217.74" and also "https://130.101.217.74"

Perhaps your router has a rule in place that is impeding just your laptop's access out of your network.  If this is a work laptop, it could have a group policy preventing connection to this site.

Comment: The ISP checked and there were no rules set up, I also factory reset the router and modem just to be sure. Also, it's not a work laptop. I cannot access the site even by just using the IP.

Comment: Do you get the same results if you are using a wired connection from that laptop?

Comment: I just checked and it works fine over a wired connection.

Comment: Have you tried "Forgetting the Network" on your laptop, rejoin the network and try a Home profile?

Comment: Yeah, it didn't fix anything. I'm so confused by this, I don't get why it won't allow the site to load only on this one network.

Comment: You might need to reinstall windows 10.  If you were able to get to these sites on your laptop with the network in question AFTER installing Windows 10: Start removing programs with an install date after Windows 10.  Run a full virus / malware scan.  Factory Reset Router + ISP statement = Something on your computer is causing the issue.  If the problem started after you installed Windows 10, start a reinstall.  Still not working: At this point I would do a clean install of Windows 10 vice downgrading to a previous version only to have the problem follow me.